# Can JavaScript's fetch() also fetch any header info such as Server like xhr can?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

The following code can fetch what the current server is, if the HTTP header contains such info:

```
function getServerName() {
  console.log(this.getResponseHeader("Server"));
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("HEAD", "somepage.html");
oReq.onload = getServerName;
oReq.send();
```

StackOverlow.com doesn't give anything so I tried JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9zLsfay6/ and it showed `nginx` and some websites showed `Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)` or `nginx/1.17.10`.

Can `fetch()` do similar things?  I tried

```
fetch("/hi").then(r => console.log("Response", r));
```

and the `Response` object and `r.headers` doesn't contain such info.

Comment: [MDN's documentation on the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is pretty exhaustive, and includes information on the options you can pass as the second argument to `fetch`....

Comment: Your fiddle shows a 404 for me, not logging anything, and when I edit it to use `onloadend` (which runs whether it is successful or not) it throws an error `Refused to get unsafe header "Server"`, which is what I would expect. The corresponding `fetch` command would be `fetch('somepage.html', { method: "HEAD" }).then(r => console.log(r.headers["Server"]))`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Strange... on my Chrome it was a `404` naturally (no such page) but the console.log showed `nginx`

Answer (score 0):

`const headers = await fetch('url', {method: 'HEAD' });`

Answer (score 0):

After more research and from @HereticMonkey's note:

```
fetch("/").then(r => console.log(r.headers.get("Server")))
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wq4r2use/